# create mailbox along with Create users graph api in o365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

We have a requirement to create office 365 user with mail account through create_user graph api. But user has been created successfully but mail account did not created.

Let us know api name to create user with mail account directly through api.

Comment: Updated answers below. Consider upvoting it and accept it as answer. So it can be useful to others in the community as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Graph API doesn't has the feature. For mailbox creation, you need to use [Exchange PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) to do it using New-Mailbox cmdlet. You can [automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) the [Exchange PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ps) with .Net as well :)

For example,

```
 $password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
 New-Mailbox -UserPrincipalName chris@contoso.com -Alias chris -Database "Mailbox Database 1" -Name ChrisAshton -OrganizationalUnit Users -Password $password -FirstName Chris -LastName Ashton -DisplayName "Chris Ashton" -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $true
```

Comment: Yes @H.Pauwelyn!!

Answer (score 0):

To do this through the graph API you need to have a license that has Exchange Online as a service plan like Microsoft 365 F3 (SPE_F1), assign your new user one these licenses on creation and a Mailbox will be created for them:

Post the following:

```
{
    "addLicenses": [
        {
            "skuId": "your SPE_F1 skuId number"
        }
    ],
    "removeLicenses": []
}
```

to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user - id}/assignLicense/
```